# Can Factory Boy fields be set to require user input?

Tags: python, factory-boy

I thought this was a trivial question but to my surprise, I couldn't find an answer.
Consider I have a factory named Foo. It has a normal field named "name" and another field named user_input for which I want to force the user to pass a value on initialization, and get an error if they don't do so. How can I achieve this?

```
import factory

class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
    name = factory.Faker("name")
    user_input = ?

# I want this to work:
foo = FooFactory(user_input="blah blah")

# and this to throw an error:
foo = FooFactory()
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution would be to use a [`factory.lazy_attribute`](https://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference.html#factory.lazy_attribute):

```py
class FooFactory(factory.Factory):
  name = factory.Faker("name")

  @factory.lazy_attribute
  def user_input(self):
    raise ValueError("FooFactory.user_input is required")
```

```py
>>> FooFactory()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...py", line 7, in user_input
ValueError: FooFactory.user_input is required

>>> FooFactory(user_input=42)
{"name": "John Doe", "user_input": 42}
```